# Blueprinting web page before loading content

Tags: html, loading

I have seen a effect in this site https://www.proptiger.com/ which i want to develop in my project.

Before loading page there is some blueprint comes like this:

[image]

I have searched but haven't found how this works. Any suggestion will appreciated.

Comment: It must be a reason of your slow internet connection or this site's bugs. Get a connection about 68 kbit/s and you'll see the same on every site.

Comment: I know about my internet connection @ForceBru. I think you haven't check example site correctly.

Answer (score 0):

they load content box with some small size style and then load the content asyncron!

you can use lib.js and ajax for it.

google have some idea about that , if you want know about that you can visit https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/UseAsync
it's also good for seo!